# Notation for the set of continuous functions with constant boundary values

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, notation

I am writing a paper about continuous functions with constant boundary, e.g. $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=C$ for all $x\in\partial X$.

Is there a standard notation for such a thing? I considered calling this set $C(X)$ but I'm worried that will be confusing since this notation is usually reserved for the set of all continuous functions on $X$.

Comment: Not sure if there is notation. I definitely would not use that notation, though.

Comment: The notation $C_{0}(X)$ is often used for continuous functions which at $\partial X$ (or, at least, I am aware of $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ being used to denote the space of continuous functions $f$ with $\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty} f(x) = 0$, which is morally the same thing as a space of functions which vanish at the boundary).  The set you want to consider seems to be an affine translation of that space, e.g. $C_{0}(X) + \{c\}$, where $c$ is some real number and the summation here is the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition).  I am not aware of any standard notation for this.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

So then $C_0([a.b])$ would mean continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$?